# How to validate multiple check box selection in a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to validate multiple check box selection in a JavaScript?

Having this syntax is not firing correctly.

```
(document.getElementById('Other1').checked || document.getElementById('Other2').checked || document.getElementById('Other').checked)
```

I presume, the issue is related to change function. How to have OR logical operator inside the change function.

Below syntax works perfectly fine for one checkbox selection.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
     $('#Other').change(CheckBoxOtherChange);

});


function CheckBoxOtherChange() 
{
    if (document.getElementById('Other').checked) {
        document.getElementById('Notes').disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('Notes').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('Notes').value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get, when you put for example `document.getElementById('Other1').checked` into the console?

Comment: Share your html and tell what exactly you want to do

Comment: I presume, the issue is related to change function. How to have OR logical operator inside the change function.

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    var values= [];
    $('#MyDiv input:checked').each(function() {
        values.push(this.val);
    });
    // now values contains all of the values of checked checkboxes
    // do something with it
});
```

Comment: Click function need a trigger ??? Instead of going through new syntax, what will be the best replacement for OR logical operation for the above syntax

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```js
function myfunc() {
var check = document.getElementById('Other2').checked || document.getElementById('Other').checked;
document.getElementById('Notes').disabled = !check;
if (!check) 
document.getElementById('Notes').value = ""
}
myfunc();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Other2" onchange="myfunc()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Other" checked onchange="myfunc()"/>
    
<input type="text" id="Notes" value="foo"/>
```

Comment: Issue is related to change function. How to have OR operator in the change function

Answer (score 0):

you can use below line of code that gives you dictionary with key as id and value as 'true' or 'false'

```
$('#click').click(function () { //#click refers to id of a button
            var dict = [];
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                dict.push({
                    key: $(this).attr('id'),
                    value: $(this)[0].checked
                });
            });
        });

    });
```